# Unable to see login window from web browser for opendaylight helium

Tags: opendaylight

I tend to build opendaylight helium. I want to use "Dlux Karaf Feature".
Although I referred following installation site and did as the procedure said, I could not get login screen at web browser.

URL: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_dlux:Dlux_Karaf_Feature

The response of the browser is "Can not open this web site."

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the login by disabling authentication.

search for the  file  org.opendaylight.aaa.authn.cfg  and then set

authEnabled=false.

For  a  faster response you might try  logging this as a bug on http://bugs.opendaylight.org/ and post  some logs. Its possible you  are not pointing your browser at  the  right port.